# other problem with sqldatareader when the condtion in sql command is arabic

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader, arabic

There is a problem with sqldatareader when the condtion in sql command is arabic like this:

```
select user_name from users where typ=N 'arabic text'
```

This does not retrieve any data although there is a user name which has this type
so can you help me please ? 
thank ^_^

Comment: (1.)  You really should use the code tags (the 101010 button) to highlight your code; it makes it much easier to read.  (2.) You say the user name is in Arabic, but your `WHERE` statement uses the column `typ`.  Are you sure you've got the right column in your `WHERE` statement?

Comment: i am beginner for this site so can you help me and tell me  how to highlight my code please

Comment: sorry i meanned there is user name which has this type i will edit it

Comment: Does the command work when you use it as SQL in Management Studio (or Query Analyzer, or which ever SQL tool you use)? Can you post the C# code you are using in case the problem is in that rather than the SQL? Can you give an example including the actual Arabic text (just to make sure there isn't an unescaped `'` character in there).

Comment: it works well on Management Studio(Query Analyzer)but in visual studio does not work will i this is My code if there is any thing not clear please tell me   http://pastebin.com/7SDf87ew  , thanks ^_^

Comment: why there is no one answer me ,is the  question not clear please post because this is arguent

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code to use a query parameter. You want to avoid putting strings directly into your queries like that (the type should most likely be normalized anyway). The main function should probably return a list of clients to your presentation layer, which would then be responsible for displaying the clients, but I didn't go that far.

Since your query worked from within Management Studio, your database collation settings should be okay.

```
public void ListClientsByType(string clientType)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    {
        IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nam FROM clients WHERE typ = @type";

        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            _CreateInputParameter(cmd, DbType.String, "@type", clientType));

        conn.Open();

        IDataReader dr = null;

        try
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Work with results here
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dr != null)
                dr.Close();
        }
    }
}

private IDbDataParameter _CreateInputParameter(
    IDbCommand cmd, DbType type, string name, object value)
{
    IDbDataParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();

    p.DbType = DbType.String;
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    p.ParameterName = name;
    p.Value = value;

    return p;
}
```